# How to change SRID in Postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am very green in both Postgis and Postgresql.
I wanted to alter the geom column in my table in order to change the SRID  but I receive this error:

```
cannot alter type of a column used by a view or rule
DETAIL:  rule _RETURN on view vw_select_location depends on column "geom"
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "ALTER TABLE public.ponds_data ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE  geometry(PointZM, 4210) USING ST_SetSRID(geom,4210);"
PL/pgSQL function updategeometrysrid(character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying,integer) line 81 at EXECUTE statement
SQL statement "SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('','',$1,$2,$3)"
PL/pgSQL function updategeometrysrid(character varying,character varying,integer) line 5 at SQL statement.
```

Please help. I wants to change the reference coordinate system to arc 1960.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message carefully: you cannot change the column  `geom` on table `ponds_data` because the view `vw_select_location` depends on it.

**Solution**: first save the view definition in a file. You can find definition of the view in pgadmin or in psql. In psql use the command

```
\d+ vw_select_location
```

Then drop the view, change the column and recreate the view with the sql statement you saved before.